# Как добавить запись в файл

Tags: файлы, java

Прошу помощи! Мне нужно записывать в файл строку с новой строки , сохраняя прежние данные.
Допустим в файле есть:

```
слово1
слово2
```

Нужно добавить "слово3", и получится текст в файле =>

```
слово1
слово2
слово3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FileWriter wr = new FileWriter(file.txt, true);
wr.append("слово 3");
wr.flush();
wr.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public FileWriter(File file, boolean append) throws IOException
```

**Constructs a FileWriter object given a File object. If the second argument is true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.**

Т.е. создаем FileWriter, в него передаем текущий файл, а вторым аргументом true, и запись будет идти в конец файла

Comment: Допустим: public FileWriter(File "D:/text.txt", true) throws IOException А где указывать текст, который хочу записать?